# permission denied when script tries to run

Tags: ubuntu, php, permissions

I have a PHP script that run's the following command using `exec()`

```
/root/gsutil/gsutil <COMMAND>
```

In my error logs I receive the following:

```
sh: 1: /root/gsutil/gsutil: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know what I can do to allow my php script to run that command?

Comment: You cannot have it to run that program as it is (unless you are root?), and quite frankly you don't want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything under /root is usually owned by the root user. PHP does usually not (and for security reasons should never) run under the root user. You should install the `gsutil` in a location where PHP has execute rights. For example, copy it to `/var/www`:

```
cp /root/gsutil/gsutil /var/www/gsutil
```

I think that under Ubuntu PHP usually runs as the `www-data` user (not 100% sure though), so you'll need to change ownership of the file to that user:

```
chown www-data.www-data /var/www/gsutil
```

Finally, make sure the file is executable for the owning user/group (www-data) by setting chmod 770:

```
chmod 770 /var/www/gsutil
```

Then set your PHP script to run `/var/www/gsutil` instead and all should run fine.

Comment: If the php script is launched by the Web server then it will run as `www-data`, otherwise it will be usual Unix rules (there's a cli install of Php available). Actually even when from apache, if it is in a user `public_html` directory, and the uuserdir mod is enabled, it will run as the user (but NOT root).

Comment: Thanks for the help. This put everything into perspective. I ended up moving the gsutil like you said (but I moved it to `/usr/bin/`) and editing where it was in `~/.bashrc` and changing `export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/gsutil` to `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin/gsutil`

Comment: Somewhere where PHP has *read* rights, not execute rights, right?